# How to use one workspace for all pipeline jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to force to work all pipeline jobs in one workspace ? For example "/home/jenkins/workspace/pipeline", but not every jobs in own workspace "/home/jenkins/workspace/job01 /home/jenkins/workspace/job02 etc."?

Goals:
Build jobs -> Code analysis (necessary run sonar-scanner in "Build jobs" workspace) -> unit tests / publish / deploy / etc.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ws command:

```
ws("/home/jenkins/workspace/pipeline") {
    // your code goes here
}
```

see: 
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#ws-allocate-workspace
https://github.com/runelabs/jenkins2-pipeline-multibranch-1-example/blob/master/Jenkinsfile#L14